# How to use webkit with Python?

Tags: python, webkit

I want to use webkit with Python but I can't figure out.

Every example in the internet is based on `PyQt5 webkit` like [this one](https://www.linuxvoice.com/build-a-web-browser-with-20-lines-of-python/) but webkit is completely deprecated from the module.

Then I tried to install `PySide` but I can't.

```
$ pip3.4 install PySide
Collecting PySide
  Using cached PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: PySide
  Running setup.py install for PySide ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/rw/62mg3wsx77l44_2rc9d8h6hc0000gn/T/pip-build-fi45551_/PySide/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/rw/62mg3wsx77l44_2rc9d8h6hc0000gn/T/pip-lkgv5ggu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Removing /private/var/folders/rw/62mg3wsx77l44_2rc9d8h6hc0000gn/T/pip-build-fi45551_/PySide/pyside_package
    running install
    running build
    Python architecture is 64bit
    error: Failed to find cmake. Please specify the path to cmake with --cmake parameter.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/rw/62mg3wsx77l44_2rc9d8h6hc0000gn/T/pip-build-fi45551_/PySide/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/rw/62mg3wsx77l44_2rc9d8h6hc0000gn/T/pip-lkgv5ggu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/rw/62mg3wsx77l44_2rc9d8h6hc0000gn/T/pip-build-fi45551_/PySide/
```

Then I tried this code, but I get `ModuleNotFoundError` for `webkit` and `gtk`. I searched to install the modules I can't find anything.

Is there any solution to use webkit in Python?

**OS:** macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Comment: The error states that it can't find cmake. So try to install cmake. `brew install cmake`. I think it should work.

Comment: @SkrewEverything It works! But have you got any suggestions about using `webkit`? I can't find any tutorials for `PyQt5` webkit.

Comment: I don't know much about WebKit but try `cefpython`.

Answer (score 0):

`PySide` is depreciated

i'll suggest you to go for `PySide2`
then

```
pip3 install PyQtWebEngine
```